# while toggling div for dynamic content all div is displaying instead of one div using React js

Tags: reactjs

```
state = {
   collapse:false
}
toggle = () => {
  this.setState({
       collapse: !this.state.collapse
  })
}
```

and in my render  i have multiple li (dynamic li)

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <span onClick={this.toggle} >Show content</span> 
    {this.state.collapse && <div>display some Content</div>}
   </li>
</ul>
```

but when i click show content all li content is showing how to control that please give solution .

expected Output:
           its should  only show one div belongs to clicked elements

Comment: You'd have to individually manage the state of all the li's. Or just don't use li's in the component, and use map in a parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to store the toggle state for each of the list items. The easiest way to do so would be by using the items index to store the boolean weather or not the content should be visible. So taking your initial example it could look like this:

```
state = {
  collapse: {}
}

toggle = (index) => {
  this.setState({
    collapse[index]: !this.state.collapse[index]
  })
}

render () {
  return (
    <ul>
      {someArray.map((index, string) =>
        <li key={i}>
          <button onClick={() => this.toggle(index)}>Show Content</button>
          {this.state.collapse[index] && <div>{string}</div>
        </li>}
    </ul>
  )
}
```